# What is the best way to link to domain root?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I'm setting up links and not sure which is the best way to link to the domain root should I do

`<a href="/">home</a>` or `<a href="http://example.com">home</a>` ?

is there a cooler way that I'm unaware of?

Comment: A quick note on accessibility: a link to `/` has no value to a screenreader, linking to `//example.com` would be preferable

Comment: I think better is / . Avoiding hardcoded URL for maintenance. You can move your website to any domain and you dont have to change that URL.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Unless you have a specific reason you want to always use HTTP, use `<a href="/">text</a>`. You'll run into problems with SSL otherwise.

There is a cooler way to do it if you're loading scripts, and that is to load cross domain scripts in a protocol-neutral way, as such:

```
<script src="//example-cdn.com/scripts/jquery-latest-min.js"></script>
```

That way you avoid the HTTP mixed content warnings in IE.

Answer (score 7):

the simpler `/` variant is portable across domains, might be considered as an advantage.

Answer (score 2):

depends on the programming language you are using.. and the web-framework.. 
in plain html `/` would be your choice (portability)