# Href value for the root domain?

Tags: django, html, django-templates, django-urls

What value do you put to href to redirect to the root domain, for example www.mydomain.com? I tried `#!` and the domain itself `www.mydomain.com` but did not work ? I'm setting up in the django template file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to link to domain root?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553796/what-is-the-best-way-to-link-to-domain-root)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `/` to set a link to the domain you are currently browsing.

```
<a href="/">link</a>
```

The reason your domain didn't work is probably because you didn't include the `http://` in your link, which will cause your browser to use your domain name as a page inside your domain: `http ://www.mydomain.com/www.mydomain.com`, and it's not exactly what you were looking for.